# @NotNull is not validating and not Producing correct Result in Spring Framework

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-mvc-test

I have created a simple Application that checks whether the given first name and lastname is null or not . i have used @NotNull annotation to check

The code for the Student.java is

```
    @NotNull(message = "Name must not be null")
    private String firstName;
    @NotNull(message = "Name must not be null")
    private String lastName;
```

i have also created StudentController.java

```
 public String processForm(@Valid @ModelAttribute("student") Student student,BindingResult bindingResult)
{
    //bindingResult is not an annotation
    if(bindingResult.hasErrors())
    {
        return "error";
    }
    else
    {
        return "success";
    }
}
```

My HTML Form is

```
<br/>
<form:input path="firstName"/>
<form:input path="lastName"/>
<br/>
```

i havent given value for firstName and the lastName , and i have submitted the form. The form redirects to "success" page which is incorrect.

My pom.xml file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>org.sample.mvc</groupId>
<artifactId>formspringmvc</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.12.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.12.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.12.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.12.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.12.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you submit the form, `String` fields are posted as *empty* but not *null*. Here are some more constraints you can use:

```
@NotNull
```

String cannot be null, however can be empty.

```
@NotEmpty
```

String cannot be null and not empty (size > 0).

```
@NotBlank
```

String cannot be null and must contain at least one non-whitespace character.

```
String firstName = null;

// @NotNull: false
// @NotEmpty: false
// @NotBlank: false
```

---

```
String firstName = "";

// @NotNull: true
// @NotEmpty: false
// @NotBlank: false
```

---

```
String firstName = " ";

// @NotNull: true
// @NotEmpty: true
// @NotBlank: false
```

---

```
String firstName = "er-han";

// @NotNull: true
// @NotEmpty: true
// @NotBlank: true
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.9.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.17.Final</version>
        </dependency>
```

adding this dependency in pom.xml resolved this issue